# Difference between arr[:]=[] and arr[]=[] in python3.x?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Is there any difference between these two lines:

```
arr[:] = []
arr = []
```

I know both of them clear list.

Comment: `arr[] = []` is a syntax error.

Comment: a quick reference for the slice notation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad. I need to sleep more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one, I think you meant `arr = []`.

What that does differently is that it has *arr* point to a **new** empty list and just decrements the refcount on the existing list.

The difference is only important if something else is pointing to the original list.

```
>>> orig = [10, 20, 30]
>>> arr = orig              # Second reference to the same list.
>>> arr[:] = []             # Clears the one list, so that arr and orig are empty
>>> orig
[]
```

Contrast that with:

```
>>> orig = [10, 20, 30]
>>> arr = orig              # Second reference to the same list.
>>> arr = []                # Points arr to a new list, leaving orig unchanged
>>> orig
[10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Been helpful.